# prediction model with python tensorflow and keras, gives error when predicting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction

I'm trying to make a prediction based on training data.

I am using 10 training data with their correct input and outputs, the training results are 80% accurate.

After training the model I use an input value and the result does not match at all.

Note: I do the training with these entry and exit numbers, and it does not give the expected result.
input: 61005363596
result: 35210192

any solution?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras

# input data
input_data_strings = [
    "61002738295", "61001799553", "61002559170","61001872384", "61002034257", "61001608325", "61001979114", "61001523797", "61002991589", "61001764730","61000101645","61002509001","61001273013","61000070543","61001387706"
]

def to_decimal(Input_value):
    return float(Input_value[0] + Input_value[1:])

input_decimals = np.array([to_decimal(input_str) for input_str in input_data_strings])

# Entry results
code = np.array([
    31211436, 21812418, 68923185,91714338, 41860727, 55489164, 12635158, 24520971, 23118193, 27233139,18433122,50231115,37236137,52134193,13135168
])

mean_input = np.mean(input_decimals)
std_input = np.std(input_decimals)
input_normalized = (input_decimals - mean_input) / std_input

mean_code = np.mean(code)
std_code = np.std(code)
code_normalized = (code - mean_code) / std_code

# Defines additional variables
batch_size = 15
hidden_layer_size = 512
loss_function = 'mean_squared_error'
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
epochs = 8000

# Model
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(units=hidden_layer_size, activation="relu", input_shape=[1]),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation="linear")
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss=loss_function
)

# Model training
print("Starting training for the model...")
historial = model.fit(input_normalized, code_normalized, 
                       epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=False)
print("Trained model")

# Display of loss during training
plt.xlabel("# Epoch")
plt.ylabel("Loss Magnitude")
plt.plot(historial.history["loss"])
plt.show()

# Function to check predictions with the prediction data.
def verify_prediction(modelo, Inputs, mean, std):
    result = []
    for input_predict in Inputs:
        input_predict_numeric = np.array([to_decimal(input_predict)])
        input_predict_normalized = (input_predict_numeric - mean) / std
        resultado_normalizado = modelo.predict(input_predict_normalized)
        resultado = resultado_normalizado * std_code + mean_code
        result.append(resultado)
    return result

# Verifying predictions with training data
training_prediction_result = verify_prediction(model, input_data_strings, mean_input, std_input)

print("Prediction results for training Inputs:")
for inputs, result in zip(input_data_strings, training_prediction_result):
    print("Input:", inputs, "Result data:", result)

# Función para predecir con un nuevo INPUT
def predict_new_value(modelo, input_new, mean, std):
    input_numeric = np.array([to_decimal(input_new)])
    input_normalizado = (input_numeric - mean) / std
    normalized_prediction = modelo.predict(input_normalizado)
    prediccion = normalized_prediction * std_code + mean_code
    return prediccion

# new value to predict input:61005363596 expected result for this value. 35210192 
input_new_strings = [
    "61005363596"
]


input_decimal_new = to_decimal(input_new_strings[0])


input_normalized_new = (input_decimal_new - mean_input) / std_input

# New input prediction
prediction_result_new = predict_new_value(model, input_new_strings[0], mean_input, std_input)

print("\nPrediction results for the new Input:")
print("Input new:", input_new_strings[0], "Result:", prediction_result_new)
```

Comment: I don't think you can expect a ~100k Model trained on 10 data points to generalize well.

Comment: and how much data I would need. could you give me help?